# IOS Auto Layout - UILabel expand to certain point

Tags: ios, constraints, autolayout

I have a `UITableViewCell` that contains a `UILabel` which expands to the text I set. I would like the label to expand only to the bottom of the `UIImageView` and not any further.

[image]

Right now, if the text is very long, it will run behind the bottom buttons. Thanks

Comment: `UILabel` is used for one-line text, use `UITextView` instead

Comment: @Carrl instead set the UILabel numberOfLines to 0, this will allow any number of lines

Comment: @Carrl , that's completely untrue. You just have to set the number of lines in the label to 0.

Comment: @SomeGuy No the label does expand to the text. That's not the problem. The problem is I do not want it to expand past the bottom of the imageView. So the text doesn't cover the bottom buttons.

Comment: @SomeGuy,@NRitH, although you can set lineNumber to 0, it is not convenient to control the presentation of AutoLayout when you use UILabel to display multiple-line text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of that less-than-or-equal constraint from the bottom of the label to the buttons, make it a greater-than-or-equal, with a constant of whatever minimum vertical space you want between the label and the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You can built a constraint in code like this:

```
let constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: videoNameLabel, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .LessThanOrEqual,toItem: thumbnailImageView, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
videoNameLabel.addConstraint(constraint)
```

or do the same in storyboard :
[image]